# Logging messages from C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, logging

I have a library in C++ which is being used by a Java app through JNI. In the Java app I'm using logback to produce logs.

Now I need to log the C++ library messages as well and I have to do it in the same file used by Java so I can have everything in chronological order.

My current approach, not yet implemented, is to create a C++ class named *Logger* that will send the messages to Java through JNI and then Java will log these messages. The disadvantage is that I'm losing Logback functionalities like logging the name of the thread or the line of the code that produced the log.

Is there a better way?

Comment: The `__LINE__` and related macros are probably your friend here.

Comment: I suspect the thread and line of code is something you will have to add to he message yourself.  Logback will try to get this for the Java code you run it as.  You would only lose the name of the thread if you are running in a different thread to that calling Logback.

Comment: You can get code line in C/C++? Other than with the `__LINE__` macro?

Comment: A silly question, why are you using C++ to do the logging.  Logging is far more expensive than what C++ is likely to save you.  You could call into C++ only as you need to and do all the logging in Java.

Comment: @dablak: Does Logback have the ability to listen on UDP port for log4j XML formatted events? If it does, you could use log4cplus to send the events to Logback this way.

Comment: @EdwardThomson That's very useful, also the `__FILE__` macro.

Comment: @wilx Logback has a [ServerSocketReceiver](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/receivers.html) system but seems like it can only be accessed by other Logback clients, not log4Cxx (see this [message](http://mailman.qos.ch/pipermail/logback-user/2008-November/000795.html)). To make it as simple as possible and without extra dependencies, I'm sending the log messages though JNI from C++ to Java and using the `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` macro. It can't detect threads but is not that important for now.

Comment: There's no good reason it shouldn't be able to detect threads.  As for why to have logging in native code, the obvious would be during development, and later for *unexpected cases* (which should not incur a performance penalty).

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be to use a common service for logging such as syslog. 
In your Java code, set the appropriate appender to write the logs to syslog. In your C++ code, simply call syslog natively. All logs will be combined in a chronological order by syslog.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution I've used in the past:-

1. Use logback with a database appender. The DB will ensure
   transactional commits in order, with a timestamp. In some databases
   you can make it a trigger and use the native timestamp which may be
   more efficient.
2. C++ part will need to have a similar appender and/or modified to write to the same table. (log4cpp works, or if you have a
   proprietary one, it may need to be modified slightly)
3. Select * from table order by timestamp asc output to a file will give you the logs in order.

In my last place we used sqlite for storing these logs as the overhead was tiny compared to oracle or a more heavy duty one and we could delete the file if needed later.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <android/log.h> 

...
int error;
...
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "Some error: code = %d", error);
...
```

Comment: My question is not for Android.